# How do I fix gulpfile.js to avoid "Did you forget to signal async completion?" when running "gulp ngrok-serve" and DO NOT have the task defined?

Tags: gulp, microsoft-teams, ngrok

I used 2 tutorial clips from Microsoft ([first](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S61Mr4WEgzM), [second](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y1_F1X95d_U)) to build a sample Teams Message Extension.

I'm down to the final step of really starting the app with the `gulp ngrok-serve` command, but I get this error message:

```
...
[16:05:29] Watching .env
[16:05:29] The following tasks did not complete: ngrok-serve, serve, watch
[16:05:29] Did you forget to signal async completion?
```

I've read various suggestions on how to fix this, but **the problem in my case** is that I don't have the "ngrok-serve" task defined in my file. It seems to be running a "*default*" version of it.

So how should I define/overwrite it, so that I can fix it's implementation, in my `gulpfile.js` file ?

Thank you.

Comment: We tried to repro this at our end and we too are facing a different issue with gulp ngrok-serve. Checking this internally, I will update you on the same.

Answer (score 0):

We were able to run the app successfully using `gulp serve`, as mentioned in the [Build your first Microsoft Teams app using the Yeoman generator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/get-started/get-started-yeoman#run-your-app) documentation. Please run the app using `gulp serve`.

Comment: But I need ngrok, my app is a message extensions, it calls a bot.

Comment: In the meantime I got to a workaround, I'm running `gulp serve --debug`.
I still get the error message `The following tasks did not complete: serve, watch. Did you forget to signal async completion?`, but after that it keeps running so I can debug...

But I still would need to know how to fix the gulpfile.